# C# Listview adding subitems

Tags: c#, listview, subitem

This is WinForms..

I have a for loop:

```
private void MagicBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (var auras in GetBuffs())
   {
      var i = new ListViewItem(auras.ToString(), 0);
      listView1.Items.AddRange(new[] { i });
   }
}
```

I want to add a simple Subitem(I get the value from a textbox) to a selected item on the list.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems.Add("4");
Solved it